# Spring Cloud Stream binding visualisation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-bus

After I enabled bindings actuator endpoints by setting the following property: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bindings`, I am supposed to see the bindings(consumer) properties.

However, after I added spring cloud bus dependency and also enable spring cloud bus, I can only see bindings properties for springCloudBus but not the bindings that I created in my project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**QUESTION: How to ensure that we can still see the bindings that we created after we enable spring cloud bus?**

When I set `spring.cloud.bus.enabled=false`, I got the following result

```
[
    {
        "name": "TestInput",
        "group": null,
        "pausable": true,
        "state": "running",
        "extendedInfo": {
            "bindingDestination": "KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='TestInput', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}",
            "ExtendedConsumerProperties": {
                "concurrency": 1,
                "instanceCount": 1,
                "maxAttempts": 3,
                "backOffInitialInterval": 1000,
                "backOffMaxInterval": 10000,
                "backOffMultiplier": 2,
                "extension": {
                    "ackEachRecord": false,
                    "autoRebalanceEnabled": true,
                    "autoCommitOffset": true,
                    "autoCommitOnError": null,
                    "startOffset": null,
                    "resetOffsets": false,
                    "enableDlq": false,
                    "dlqName": null,
                    "dlqProducerProperties": {
                        "bufferSize": 16384,
                        "compressionType": "none",
                        "sync": false,
                        "batchTimeout": 0,
                        "messageKeyExpression": null,
                        "headerPatterns": null,
                        "configuration": {},
                        "admin": {
                            "replicationFactor": null,
                            "replicasAssignments": {},
                            "configuration": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "recoveryInterval": 5000,
                    "trustedPackages": null,
                    "standardHeaders": "none",
                    "converterBeanName": null,
                    "idleEventInterval": 30000,
                    "configuration": {},
                    "admin": {
                        "replicationFactor": null,
                        "replicasAssignments": {},
                        "configuration": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "TestInput2",
        "group": null,
        "pausable": true,
        "state": "running",
        "extendedInfo": {
            "bindingDestination": "KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='TestInput2', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}",
            "ExtendedConsumerProperties": {
                "concurrency": 1,
                "instanceCount": 1,
                "maxAttempts": 3,
                "backOffInitialInterval": 1000,
                "backOffMaxInterval": 10000,
                "backOffMultiplier": 2,
                "extension": {
                    "ackEachRecord": false,
                    "autoRebalanceEnabled": true,
                    "autoCommitOffset": true,
                    "autoCommitOnError": null,
                    "startOffset": null,
                    "resetOffsets": false,
                    "enableDlq": false,
                    "dlqName": null,
                    "dlqProducerProperties": {
                        "bufferSize": 16384,
                        "compressionType": "none",
                        "sync": false,
                        "batchTimeout": 0,
                        "messageKeyExpression": null,
                        "headerPatterns": null,
                        "configuration": {},
                        "admin": {
                            "replicationFactor": null,
                            "replicasAssignments": {},
                            "configuration": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "recoveryInterval": 5000,
                    "trustedPackages": null,
                    "standardHeaders": "none",
                    "converterBeanName": null,
                    "idleEventInterval": 30000,
                    "configuration": {},
                    "admin": {
                        "replicationFactor": null,
                        "replicasAssignments": {},
                        "configuration": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

After I set `spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true`, I can only see the properties for springCloudBus

```
[
{
    "name": "springCloudBus",
    "group": null,
    "pausable": true,
    "state": "running",
    "extendedInfo": {
        "bindingDestination": "KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='springCloudBus', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}",
        "ExtendedConsumerProperties": {
            "concurrency": 1,
            "instanceCount": 1,
            "maxAttempts": 3,
            "backOffInitialInterval": 1000,
            "backOffMaxInterval": 10000,
            "backOffMultiplier": 2,
            "extension": {
                "ackEachRecord": false,
                "autoRebalanceEnabled": true,
                "autoCommitOffset": true,
                "autoCommitOnError": null,
                "startOffset": null,
                "resetOffsets": false,
                "enableDlq": false,
                "dlqName": null,
                "dlqProducerProperties": {
                    "bufferSize": 16384,
                    "compressionType": "none",
                    "sync": false,
                    "batchTimeout": 0,
                    "messageKeyExpression": null,
                    "headerPatterns": null,
                    "configuration": {},
                    "admin": {
                        "replicationFactor": null,
                        "replicasAssignments": {},
                        "configuration": {}
                    }
                },
                "recoveryInterval": 5000,
                "trustedPackages": null,
                "standardHeaders": "none",
                "converterBeanName": null,
                "idleEventInterval": 30000,
                "configuration": {},
                "admin": {
                    "replicationFactor": null,
                    "replicasAssignments": {},
                    "configuration": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Steps to replicate:

1. Clone the project from https://github.com/HLTan94/SpringCloudStreamBindingsDemo
2. Set `spring.cloud.bus.enabled`
3. Execute `curl -X GET http://localhost:9999/bindings`

Comment: did you mean `http://localhost:9999/actuator/bindings`?

Comment: I have set `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/`. So it is `http://localhost:9999/bindings` but not `http://localhost:9999/actuator/bindings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce it and discovered that this is actually a bug on our end. You can track it [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1418). In any event we should have a service release by the end of July (i.e., 2.0.2)